# iOS app Crash in 4.3 using GCD

Tags: objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch

Am calling a method in background queue as,

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^(void) {
[self loadImage:imageUrlString];
});
 // This is the loadImage method:

- (void)loadImage:(NSString *)imageUrlString
{        
    // calling a method in main queue to add a preloader

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {


                  [self addPreloader];
    });

    // converting the url content to NSData
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString]];

    // calling a method in main queue to load the image with imageData.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        [self setImage:imageData];
    });  
}
```

But the app crashes. 
This is my Crash log: bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0xc9a5010: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the full stack trace of the crash?

Comment: @ rob mayoff : This is the crash log.. bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0xc9a5010: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with that code on its face. I don't think there's enough information/context here to tell what's wrong.